# How can i get next page after submit form using Ghost.py

Tags: javascript, python, forms, form-submit, ghost.py

I'm using Ghost.py for filling form. After submit form i get same page.
Code:

```
url_local = 'url'
gh = Ghost()
page, name = gh.create_page()
page.open(url_local, wait_onload_event=True)
page.wait_for_selector('#id_username')
page.set_field_value('#id_username', '1')
page.set_field_value('#id_password', '1')
page.capture_to("1.png")
page.fire_on('form', 'submit')

page.capture_to("2.png")
```

How can i get next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submitting try to wait using

```
page, resources = ghost.wait_for_page_loaded()
```

then capture it